# Get stored data from Timmy Fingerprint machine using php library

Tags: php, fingerprint

I'm currently using Timmy fingerprint machine for attendance system. When I trying to connect to Timmy fingerprint machine using zkteco php library, it's getting an error saying

> "socket_sendto(): Host lookup failed [11001]: No such host is known".

Device Name: Timmy TM20 Fingerprint Machine.
I've used rats/zkteco laravel library (https://github.com/raihanafroz/zkteco) and used Ethernet to connect fingerprint machine with my laptop.

Is there any other ways that I can get all the data from fingerprint through PHP?

Comment: The error sounds like you just mistyped the hostname or IP address of the device, or it isn't accessible from where your php code is running. It's difficult to help because you provided no details about the device, no details of the physical configuration of how it connects to your network, and no code. Therefore we cannot really analyse the situation to diagnose the exact problem or identify a solution. See also [ask].

Comment: OK. That doesn't mean much to us. Please provide a link to some relevant documentation for it, and provide the other info I mentioned. Do not add it piecemeal to the comments, instead please [edit] your question so it's all visible and in one place, and coherent. Thanks

Comment: That is a bit more info, but not everything that was requested or needed

Comment: It was my mistake. I've added the IP address incorrectly. The issue is solved, but cannot connect to the device. Is there any plugin which you recommend in order to connect to Timmy fingerprint machine?

Comment: We don't do recommendations here - see the [help/on-topic]. And you still provided no info about how this device works, anyway.  But why can't you connect - are you getting an error or something? Again please provide a [mre] of the issue.

Comment: found out a solution. I've sent a support mail to the product owners and received required documents for the setup process. Thank you soo much guys for the support given.

Comment: Great. Next time you're in this kind of situation, make that the _first_ thing you do.